Suggestions for references about filtrations and their topological properties
I've started reading Qing Liu's Algebraic Geometry, and whilst the prerequisites on multilinear algebra and flat modules were familiar, I've hit a wall with his discussion of the topology endowed on a group by a descending filtration. So far, the conventional references on commutative algebra I've seen recommended more generally under other threads have failed to provide me sufficient detail to better understand the material, and so I was wondering if anybody had suggestions for references on filtrations and the properties' of the topology they endow on a group.

J.P.May has  nice notes about it here.
